# Trying to send an object as context from a parent to children. Why do the children receive only undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Code in parent component `<Home/>`:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext} from "react";

import LandingPage from "./LandingPage.js";
import AnotherComponent from "./AnotherComponent.js";
import OneMoreComponent from "./OneMoreComponent.js";

// Create context to share data with all descendants
// of this parent component:
export const MenuContext = createContext() 

export default function Home(){

  const myObject = {
p0: { // properties and values in here },
p1: { // properties and values in here },
p2: { // properties and values in here },
}

const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);
// pageIndex gets set elsewhere and is not 
// relevant to my question

const [iconsObject, setIconsObject] = useState(myObject);

    return (
    <div>

<MenuContext.Provider value={iconsObject}>
// Conditionally render child components:
// pageIndex gets set elsewhere and is not 
// relevant to my question

<LandingPage   
  isThisPageActive = {pageIndex === 0} 
  />

  <AnotherComponent 
  isThisPageActive = {pageIndex === 1}  
  />

  <OneMoreComponent 
  isThisPageActive = {pageIndex === 2}  
  />

</MenuContext.Provider>

   </div>
   
           ); // end return
 
                      } // end <Home/> declaration
```

And here is one of the child components (`<LandingPage/>`):

```
import React, { useState, useContext} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

// Context:
import MenuContext from "./Home.js"



export default function LandingPage({
    isThisPageActive 
    
                                    }) {

// Consume the context:                                    
const bigObject = useContext(MenuContext);

let renderThis

if (isThisPageActive) {
renderThis = (

<Button
     onClick={bigObject.p0.someProperty}
 >
Click me!
</Button>

)
                      }

if (!isThisPageActive) {
renderThis = null
}

return (
    <div>
    {renderThis}
    </div>
               )


                        }
```

The problem is that in Chrome developer tools I get this error message:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'p0')
at LandingPage (LandingPage.js:xx:x)**

In other words where I am setting the Button's onClick:

```
onClick={bigObject.p0.someProperty}
```

I cannot understand why bigObject is undefined.

Comment: Change `import MenuContext from "./Home.js"` to `import { MenuContext } from "./Home.js"`. Getting in the habit of debugging your code will help you find this error. If the object is undefined, look at where it's coming from, and use `console.log` to check your assumptions.

Comment: thank you also for the advice :)